# What is the right battery-powered pump to rinse salt off of a car before parking?

Tags: rust, carwash

I am looking for the following pump to rinse salt off a car before parking.

The effect of the pump would be no more than pouring water on the roof, except that it would spray it to cover a larger area quickly.

There would be enough pressure to push the slush deposits in the wheel wells out, but it need not (should not) be a power washer.

I would walk around with a 2-4 gallon ~ 8-16 litre container of fresh water, with a hose from the container to the pump. I would use the pump's water-out hose to rinse the car.

Does such a thing exist?

I have a portable swimming pool pump that would do the job just fine when dunked into a water container, but with slush all around, I'd much rather not have to worry about electrocution (even with GFCI), nor have to drag a power cable that's a pain to stow in freezing temperatures.

##### Why's

- *Why not just use a regular garden hose?* 1- Because it would mean winterizing the faucet after every rinse, and 2- because I'm not sure the garage door would remain closed with a water hose underneath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Frame Challenge** ([What's that?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6843))

Either this is a shopping question, which we don't answer and which is typically closed by voters in short order, or you believe that it's commonplace for people to walk around with a bucket of water and a battery powered pump to clean salt off their car, and you innocently want to know what pump everybody else uses.

If it's a shopping question, please use a search engine or go to the 500 pound gorilla of online shopping, where I see over 400 products under "battery powered water pump."

The way most people deal with the salt issue in winter is either (1) go to a car wash, (2) use a [frost free sillcock](https://www.homedepot.ca/search?q=frost%20free%20sillcock#!q=frost%20free%20sillcock) and a garden hose, or (3) hope for the best and wait for the spring rains to wash off your car. I can almost guarantee that if you go the bucket and battery pump route, you'll be the only one in your neighborhood doing that.

With a frost free sillcock, there is no winterizing. As soon as you turn off the valve and disconnect the hose to bring it in the house where it won't freeze, the sillcock drains itself automatically and it is thereafter not subject to freezing. This is because the valve that cuts off the water is located deep within the house on the warm side of the insulation. The knob outside the house turns the valve via a long shaft.

[image: e]

This really is the best solution to your problem, since you can use unlimited water and you get full water mains pressure.

Don't forget to rinse the undercarriage, where the worst rust will take hold if salt is not washed off. There are undercarriage washing gizmos that can be slid under the vehicle on a long pole.

(Photo: homedepot.ca)