Is the difference between consumer-level and pro-level ceramic coating qualitative or only quantitative?
The established method of polyurethane coating a car (which you'd often see as a thin line on cars where only the front was so protected) is losing favor to ceramic coating.
On the market I see "ceramic coating" sprays available to consumers. I also see professional shops and dealers advertising ceramic coating.
One is two orders of magnitude more expensive than the other (which can hardly be justified by labor alone), and so I'm wondering whether these two are even related, aside from the name.
Is the difference between consumer-level and pro-level ceramic coating:

qualitative (the pros use a different substance and/or apply the ceramic coating using a method entirely different from the one an amateur would use), or only
quantitative (the pros put a much more substantial layer that lasts for years rather than for few months)?


Impossible to say without knowing the brands of ceramic coating we are comparing.
Forget everything!  There is a new consumer product called Turtle Wax Hybrid Solutions Scratch Repair Kit.  It's thick enough to completely cover car wash swirls and durable enough to last several years.  Two-to-three kits enough to do the entire car, costing under $50.  You can do it yourself if you're handy with a power buffer.
The shine is like showroom new.  I just did my Mercedes E350.  You will love it!

Good hint, but it's for this reason that I only ever use touchless car washes. They don't work as well, and so it's necessary to complement them and occasionally do the labor manually using a shammy. The other problem that's very tough to solve — at least for those where the roads are flooded with tons of salt over winter — is to rinse the underside https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/96224/57044  . Do chime in if you have hints.

Why does this feel like an advertisement?

@Paulster2 - I've been posting here for years, so I'm no salesman.  Good ahead and try the stuff.  You will become a walking advertisement, too!
